# setDisplayOrientation(90) is not working in android (Video Recording)

Tags: android, service, android-camera, android-mediarecorder, video-recording

When I record video in portrait or landscape mode, the resulted video 
orientation is different from actual one. I found a solution to use `setDisplayOrientation()` method but it also does not work. It gives `RuntimeException`. Please tell me how to resolve this problem.

Thanks in advance.
This is in a Service not in Activity

```
camera = Camera.open(cameraType);
                camera.unlock();
android.hardware.Camera.CameraInfo info =
             new android.hardware.Camera.CameraInfo();
     android.hardware.Camera.getCameraInfo(cameraId, info);
     int rotation = activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay()
             .getRotation();
     int degrees = 0;
     switch (rotation) {
         case Surface.ROTATION_0: degrees = 0; break;
         case Surface.ROTATION_90: degrees = 90; break;
         case Surface.ROTATION_180: degrees = 180; break;
         case Surface.ROTATION_270: degrees = 270; break;
     }

     int result;
     if (info.facing == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) {
         result = (info.orientation + degrees) % 360;
         result = (360 - result) % 360;  // compensate the mirror
     } else {  // back-facing
         result = (info.orientation - degrees + 360) % 360;
     }
     camera.setDisplayOrientation(result);
```

Comment: @Vishal Shende: On orientation change the activity will get recreated. You need to release the camera first on orientation change and recreate it. If camera is not released, then it will give exception.

Comment: In above code when i reached to the setDisplayOrientation(result) method ,it gives runtimeexception.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to record the video in whatever orientation it is recording(but have the current orientation noted) and set the orientation of the video using

mMediaRecorder.**setOrientationHint** (degreesRotation)

As for the runtime exception, it could be because the camera's preview is running(As per Developer's Guide, "Starting from API level 14, this method 'setDisplayOrientation' can be called when preview is active."). Therefore,
Stop the preview and/or release the camera before changing orientation.